# How can I sum values from a form in Python Flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to sum the values from a form in Python Flask. How can I do that?

```
<form action="/count_daily_calories" method="post">
      <p>Input 1: <input type="text" name="daily_calories" value="input"></p>
      <p>Input 2: <input type="text" name="daily_calories" value="input"></p>
      <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
      <p>Result: <input type="text" name="result_dc" value="result"></p>
</form>
```

Flask Code:

```
@app.route('/daily_intake')
def daily_intake():
    if 'user_id' not in session:
        return redirect('/')
    return render_template("daily_intake.html")
```

Here I keep getting all the errors:

```
@app.route('/count_daily_calories', methods=['POST'])
def count_daily_calories():
    if 'user_id' not in session:
        return redirect('/')
    float(request.form['result']) += float(request.form['input'])
    return redirect('/daily_intake')
```

I keep getting the errors can't assign to function call

Comment: get strings from `request.form`, convert string to numbers and sum them.

Comment: my first thought was to convert but my way is not working. how can i do that/

Comment: first get values from `request.form`. If you get error then show full error message in question - we can't read in your mind.

Comment: BTW: if you want to calculate without reloading page then you need JavaScript/AJAX to send data and receive result.

Comment: I updated it. It said can't assign to function call

Comment: Is this a homework or school assignment? It really looks like one.

Comment: copy FULL error message - not your description.

Comment: Nope. I am a recent developer in Flask and this is my first project on creating a website that helps people count calories of the food they consume.

Comment: you can't do `float() += float()` - you have to do `result = float() + float()`

Comment: Syntax error: can't assign to function call

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") **in question** (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: BTW: using `request.form['result'] = ... ` will not put value in form - `request.form` is used only to get value sended from browser. To put value you have to add it to `render_template(..., result=result)` and inside HTML use `<input ...>{{ result }}</input>`

Comment: That is the only line I'm getting in CMD.

Comment: I am getting this error now:werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'input'

Answer (score 3):

It will be easier to do all in one function. Using `redirect` you would have to keep values in cookies to get it later from cookies after redirection and put it in form

I get values from browser using `request.form`, convert it to float() and next I sum values. When I have result then I render again page with values - and I use `{{ result }}` in HTML to put values in correct place.

In example I use `render_template_string` instead of `render_template` only to make it simpler to copy and run - all will be in one file.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        vals = request.form.getlist('daily_calories')
        val1 = float(vals[0])
        val2 = float(vals[1])
        result = val1 + val2
    else:
        val1 = ''
        val2 = ''
        result = ''

    return render_template_string('''
<form action="/" method="POST">
<p>Input 1: <input type="number" name="daily_calories" value="{{ val1 }}"></p>
<p>Input 2: <input type="number" name="daily_calories" value="{{ val2 }}"></p>
<input type="submit" value="Calculate">
<p>Result: <input type="number" name="result_dc" value="{{ result }}"></p>
</form>
''', val1=val1, val2=val2, result=result)

app.run()
```

---

**EDIT:** Similar example using only `JavaScript` to get values, calculate sum and put it in form. It blocks button to send data to server and flask doesn't have to calculate it.

If user doesn't use JavaScript then it will not work and it would need mix with previous version.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''
<form action="/" method="post">
      <p>Input 1: <input type="number" name="daily_calories" value="" id="val1"></p>
      <p>Input 2: <input type="number" name="daily_calories" value="" id="val2"></p>
      <input type="submit" value="Calculate" id="button_calculate">
      <p>Result: <input type="number" name="result_dc" value="" id="result"></p>
</form>
<script>
var val1_input = document.getElementById("val1");
var val2_input = document.getElementById("val2");
var result_input = document.getElementById("result");
var button_input = document.getElementById("button_calculate");
button_input.onclick = function(event) {
    result_input.value = parseFloat(val1_input.value) + parseFloat(val2_input.value);
    //event.preventDefault(); // don't send to server
    return false; // don't send to server
}
</script>
''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

---

**EDIT:**

This example uses pure `JavaScript` to send `AJAX` to url `/calculate` which sends result.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''
<form action="/" method="POST">
      <p>Input 1: <input type="number" name="daily_calories" value="" id="val1"></p>
      <p>Input 2: <input type="number" name="daily_calories" value="" id="val2"></p>
      <input type="submit" value="Calculate" id="button_calculate">
      <p>Result: <input type="number" name="result_dc" value="" id="result"></p>
</form>
<script>
var val1_input = document.getElementById("val1");
var val2_input = document.getElementById("val2");
var result_input = document.getElementById("result");
var button_input = document.getElementById("button_calculate");

button_input.onclick = function(event) {
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('val1', val1_input.value)
    formData.append('val2', val2_input.value)

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
        {
            //alert(request.responseText);
            result_input.value = request.responseText;
        }
    }

    request.open('POST', "/calculate");

    // execute the request
    request.send(formData);

    return false; // don't send button to server
}
</script>
''')

@app.route('/calculate', methods=['POST'])
def calcualte():
    val1 = float(request.form.get('val1'))
    val2 = float(request.form.get('val2'))

    return str(val1+val2)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app.run()
```

Comment: I added example which uses only JavaScript to calculate it - it doesn't have to send it to flask. Eventual JavaScript could use AJAX to send data and receive only result and put this result in HTML in browser.

Comment: Thank you very much! You have been very helpful!